# Meaning of "What did he do that had not always been done?"

Tags: word-usage, sentence-meaning

This is a speech given by Valery, but I have encountered a few questions.
First, what does the word "task" in the first sentence mean? Second, what does the sentence below in bold mean? Does it mean that everything he does is just normal, as everyone else does the same thing?

> More  than  one  critic  has  taken  him  to  **task**  rather 
>   harshly, and  naively, for being so knowledgeable and  for 
>   not  being unaware  of what  he  knew. What  was he  sup­
>   posed  to  do? **What  did  he  do  that  had  not  always  been 
>   done?**  Nothing  is  newer  than  the  standard  of  absolute 
>   newness imposed as an  obligation on  writers

Comment: To [take to task](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/take_to_task) is an idiom meaning to lecture, berate, admonish, hold someone accountable.

Comment: Re the idiomatic usage [take to task:](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/take+to+task) *This term, dating from the mid-1700s, at first meant either assigning or challenging someone to a task. Its current sense dates from the late 1800s.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To "take someone to task" is roughly synonymous with "to remonstrate with them" - a strong rebuttal, scolding or complaint.

"What did he do that has not always been done" in this context is accusing him of lack of originality. A slightly less complex sentence with a similar theme would be.

What has he done, which has not already been done by others for a long time?